# Errors while overloading + and =

Tags: c++, overloading

I want to overload the operators + and = for my matrix class. My code is:

```
    friend float* operator+(const Matrix& m)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < (int)(m._n*m._n); i++)
            _m[i] = _m[i] + m._m[i];
    };

    friend Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& m)
    {
        std::swap(_m, m._m);
        return *this;
    };
```

with `_m` the data and `_n` the size of the square matrices. But my compiler gives me the following errors:

```
main.cpp:161:45: error: ‘Matrix& operator=(const Matrix&)’ must be a nonstatic member function
main.cpp: In function ‘float* operator+(const Matrix&)’:
main.cpp:192:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Matrix::_m’
main.cpp:158:13: error: from this location
main.cpp:192:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Matrix::_m’
main.cpp:158:21: error: from this location
main.cpp:159:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
```

For the first error, I have read that it has to be directly in the class, but even when I put it in there, I still get the error.  For the second error, I have no idea how to solve this. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: How does `float*` makes sense as a result of adding two matrices?

Comment: If you put these functions in a class as members, then you can't have them declared as `friend`. That makes the functions non-member functions.

Comment: You can't swap from a `const` reference. You need to pass by value or make a local copy.

Comment: Your `operator+` should be const. It should return a new matrix. It shouldn't modify `this` matrix.

Comment: @BartoszKP: My matrices consists of two arrays of length nxn, data type float. What would be a better return type for this function?

Comment: How about `Matrix`? Adding two matrices should result in a matrix, not some internal representation the caller code shouldn't care about.

Comment: My matrix is created dynamically, so I can not create a new Matrix within this function and return it.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with `Matrix result; result._m[...] = ...; return result;` ?

Comment: My matrix constructor needs a pointer to an existing memory space, which has to be allocated before. As far as I know, I can not allocate this in a function and return it because of memory leaks. Is this correct?

Comment: That sounds like a bad design. Either manage memory in your class (constructor, copy constructor, copy assignment: allocation; destructor: deallocation) or implement it in terms of an existing data structure like `std::vector` which I **highly** recommend.

Comment: You should take the time to read what a [`friend` declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) means. And as @leemes says your `operator+` should be `const` and returning a `Matrix`. Maybe you want to implement `operator+=`? If so, it should probably return `Matrix&`.

Comment: @leemes: I can not change the memory implementation, it is given by our lecturer...

Comment: Please explain your lecturer that this is a bad design and ask him why he chose hit. So if you're bound to such a bad design, what you want is actually `operator+=`, that is, not returning a new, but modifying an existing Matrix.

Answer (score 5):

If you're defining something as `friend` in a class, it is **not** a member function, but a free-standing function can be defined (literally) inside of a class for convenience.

So `operator=()` should certainly not be `friend` but a simple member `const Matrix& operator=(Matrix m)` or `const Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& m)`. By the way, you cannot use `std::swap()` if your parameter is `const Matrix& m`. You have to follow the [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

For `operator+()` you should choose:

- `friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix& m1, const Matrix& m2)`
- `Matrix operator+(const Matrix& m1) const`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood the friend concept a bit here:

Either use:

```
friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix& lhs,const Matrix& rhs);
```

Within the class and define the free function outside.
(How you want to return a float* I do not know, so my implementation return a Matrix)
Then you have to access your member variables like this:

```
{
    Matrix result; //insert correct constructor here.
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)(lhs._n*rhs._n); i++)
        result._m[i] = lhs._m[i] + rhs._m[i];
};
```

Or you go for an member operator+ like this

```
Matrix operator+(const Matrix& rhs) const;
```

Then you only have differ between access between `this`, `rhs` and your return value, and since you are returning a copy, you can keep it const correct.

**Remember that friend functions does not have a `this`and thus cannot access member variable directly.**

For the assignment operator you cannot use a friend overload, this is because there already exist a default assignment operator provided by the compiler.

So here you have to provide within your class:

```
Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& a);
```